# AutoMapper - how to troubleshoot missing mappings?

Tags: automapper

I have used AutoMapper a lot, in many applications, and I love it.  I understand how to use it, but in my current project I am creating many new mappings (maybe ~50 -75 properties), and I'd like a way to troubleshoot missing mappings.  Currently the exceptions I get from AutoMapper are as follows:

```
Inner Exception 1:
AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.

Inner Exception 2:
AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
```

With no details, finding and fixing the missing mapping is a very time-consuming job.  I know how to do it, but it sure seems there should be a way to get a better exception out of AutoMapper.  I know some of you will want to see my code, my models, the structure, everything, but it's a lot of nested models and a lot of code to post.  I don't want a fix for just this error, I'd like a better way, in general, to solve this class of problem.

Comment: Look at `exception.ToString()`.

Comment: That's helpful, thank you.  It seems odd that the exception message, and inner exception message are of so little help, but ToString() gives you more information.  Is this normal?

Comment: Normal or not, anything other that `ToString()` is bound to hide smth :) And in some cases, it happens to be important. AM is only one such case.

Comment: If you post his as an answer I will mark it as the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The only reliable way to get complete exception information is to call `ToString` on the `Exception` object.